# Как установить android studio на машину без интернета?

Tags: android, linux, junit

Всем, привет!

- есть 2 машины с инетом и без
- требуется установить студию на машину без интеренета
- установил android studio (linux) на машине с выходом
- скачал все обновления
- перенес архивы из \opt и \home на машину без сети
- подобным образом развернул Genymotion

при запуске проект ругается на junit:

> Failed to resolve: junit:junit: 4.12

и весь MainActivity.java красный, классы не найдены:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'

удалил строку `testCompile 'junit:junit: 4.12'` из `../app/build.gradle`

классы определились, покраснения исчезли

но при запуске ругается на ExampleUnittest.java

я так понял, что junit не скачивается через `SDK Manager' или он чисто онлайновый?

вопрос:
как установить junit локально, если это не возможно, то как убрать его из проекта?

Спасибо.

Comment: на машине все равно понадобится интернет. вы библиотеки не сможете нормально подключать

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо установить еще [Support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

junit можете просто удалить из build.gradle и ExampleUnittest.java впридачу.

Comment: `Android Support Library v.23.2.1 - Installed` , но все равно ругается.
Как правильно удалить `ExampleUnittest.java`? Закомментировал содержимое, все равно ругается.